# Your Gemfile.lock is corrupt. The following gems are missing from the DEPENDENCIES section:

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundle, gemfile.lock

I am installing one app and I was in this step that I should run bundle install and I get this error

```
enter code here➜  mavatar git:(master) ✗ bundle install 
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/
Fetching version metadata from http://rubygems.org/
Fetching dependency metadata from http://rubygems.org/
Using rake 0.9.2
Using multi_json 1.8.2
Using bcrypt-ruby 3.0.1
Using builder 3.0.4
Using i18n 0.6.5
Using erubis 2.7.0
Using rack 1.3.6
Using hike 1.2.1
Using tilt 1.3.3
Installing nokogiri 1.5.0 with native extensions

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory: /home/farbodi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0-

dev/gems/nokogiri-1.5.0/ext/nokogiri
/home/farbodi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0-dev/bin/ruby -r
./siteconf20160806-31805-mdcnrl.rb extconf.rb
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
 necessary
 libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details. 
You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
--with-opt-dir
--without-opt-dir
--with-opt-include
--without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
--with-opt-lib
--without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
--with-make-prog
--without-make-prog
--srcdir=.
--curdir
--ruby=/home/farbodi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0-dev/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
 extconf.rb:10:in `<main>': uninitialized constant Config (NameError)
 Did you mean?  RbConfig
           CONFIG

 extconf failed, exit code 1

 Gem files will remain installed in /home/farbodi/.rvm/gems/ruby- 
 2.3.0-dev/gems/nokogiri-1.5.0 for inspection.
 Results logged to /home/farbodi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0- 
 dev/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/nokogiri-1.5.0/gem_make.out
 Your Gemfile.lock is corrupt. The following gems are missing from the    
 DEPENDENCIES section: 'archive-tar-minitar' 'hoe' 'rcov'
```

So I tried to run this : `gem update`

```
gem install hoe
gem install rcov
gem install archive-tar-minitar 
gem install nokogiri -v 1.5.0 which gives me ERROR: Failed to build   gem native extension. error
```

I also installed bundle older version, I can pass this step but I get same problem in somewhere else. 
I also used rvm and my ruby version is ruby 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290) [x86_64-linux] , And Bundler version 1.12.5

I am new to ruby and gem and bundle I am all confused and I don't know how to start to learn what is going on and how to solve the errors.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install some system packages.

If you are using redhat based, install `libxml2` and `libxslt` and `zlib-devel`

and if you are using debian based, install `zlib1g-dev` and `liblzma-dev` packages

Comment: I forgot to mention I also installed them.

Comment: @FarbodGhiasi So did you try this before : `gem install nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries` ?

Comment: yes I get this errors:
ERROR:  Error installing nokogiri:
 ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
ERROR: cannot discover where libxml2 is located on your system. please make sure `pkg-config` is installed.
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Comment: @FarbodGhiasi Can you please show the content of `/home/farbodi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0- 
 dev/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/nokogiri-1.5.0/gem_make.out`?

Comment: Are you sure `libxml2` is installed? What is your OS?

Comment: current directory: /home/farbodi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0-dev/gems/nokogiri-1.5.0/ext/nokogiri
/home/farbodi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0-dev/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20160806-32640-k0nte5.rb extconf.rb
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You

Comment: may
need configuration options.
Provided configuration options:
 --with-opt-dir
 --without-opt-dir
 --with-opt-include
 --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
 --with-opt-lib
 --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
 --with-make-prog
 --without-make-prog
 --srcdir=.
 --curdir
 --ruby=/home/farbodi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0-dev/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
extconf.rb:10:in `<main>': uninitialized constant Config (NameError)
Did you mean?  RbConfig
               CONFIG

extconf failed, exit code 1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120336/discussion-between-farbod-ghiasi-and-ebrahim-pasbani).